# Members removed from team still have custom model driven view visible

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, powerapps

Working on powerapps.  Created multiple teams and views specific for each team.  I am able to share/assign a view to a team and only the members in that team can see that view. The issue is that when removing a member from a team, they can still see that view, but lack the access to actually see any records in that view.

Is there a way to prevent the removed user from even seeing that the view exists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it shared to the business unit and the team perhaps? That could explain why a user still can see after being removed from a team but not from the business unit.